# error in mysql query - inner join inside where

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

i got this error:

```
for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN oferta B ON A.oferta_id_oferta = B.id_oferta AND B.oferta = &quot;design' at line 4
```

i can't make a inner join inside a where clause ? or exists other problem with this query ?

```
UPDATE `oferta_has_tags` A
    SET fraccao = "1/7"
    WHERE (
    INNER JOIN oferta B
    ON A.oferta_id_oferta = B.id_oferta
    AND B.oferta = "designer"
    AND B.estado = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express it as a simple `IN`:

```
UPDATE oferta_has_tags
SET fraccao = '1/7'
WHERE oferta_id_oferta IN (
    SELECT id_oferta 
    FROM oferta
    WHERE oferta = 'designer'
    AND estado = 0)
```

Also, changed double quotes (`"`) to single quotes (`'`) - using double quotes will cause an error

Answer (score 1):

The query is wrong. It must have SELECT and FROM clauses:

It must be something like this:

> UPDATE `oferta_has_tags` A
>       SET fraccao = "1/7"
>       WHERE id = ( SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE something = somevalue  )

Make sure that the subquery should return exactly 1 value. If you want to update multiple records using above query, replace "=" with "IN". Like this:

> UPDATE `oferta_has_tags` A
>       SET fraccao = "1/7"
>       WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM yourtable WHERE something = somevalue  )

Hope it helps...